# How to install a second Grafana instance to run alongside an existing Grafana instance?

Tags: centos7, grafana

I have a CentOS 7.6.1810 server running Grafana v4.3.2.  My Grafana dashboards require templating with MySQL query variables, which are not supported until Grafana v4.5.0 (refer to https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/9137, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042723/unable-to-setup-grafana-template-with-mysql, and https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/8855).

So my solution is to update Grafana from v4.3.2 to the current version (v5.4.2).  I have already confirmed this works on a staging server.

The existing Grafana instance has production dashboards running on it, and to avoid service interruption, my team lead has informed me that I need to install a second instance of Grafana v5.4.2 running alongside the existing v4.3.2 instance, copy all of the dashboards, plugins, and data sources into the new instance, and confirm everything works before turning down the old instance.

Unfortunately, while I have been able to find some documentation about upgrading an existing Grafana instance in place, I have not been able to find anything about installing a second Grafana instance alongside an existing one.  I have not even been able to find any documentation to indicate whether 2 simultaneous Grafana instances on the same server is even a technically feasible arrangement.

Does anyone know whether this is technically feasible, and if so, does an instruction guide or document for this exist somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

- Make a snapshot of Grafana v4.3.2
- Run that snapshot
- Tried to upgrade Grafana in-place

Check whether some dashboard is broken.

Running more than one grafana with the same data source is feasible as long as the firewall of data source allows it.

Comment: thank you -- we ended up backing up the existing Grafana config, then updating to the current version.  fortunately the update went through with no issues, and there were no interruptions to the production dashboards.